# How to get multiple drive time between two addresses using arcGIS api

Tags: python, pandas, arcgis

I'm using the ArcGIS api (ArcMap - 10.5.1), and I'm trying to get the drive time between two addresses. I can get the drive time between two points, but I don't know how to iterate over multiple points. I have one hundred addresses. I keep getting

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_tools'

This is the Pandas dataframe I'm working with. I have two columns with indexes. Column 1 is the origin address and column two is the second address. If possible, I would love to make a new row with the drive time.

```
df2
          Address_1                                        Address_2
0  1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500    2 15th St NW, Washington
1  400 Broad St, Seattle, WA 98109                   325 5th Ave N, Seattle
```

This is the link where I grabbed the code from 
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/performing-route-analyses/

I tried hacking this code. Specifically the code below.

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

#empty list - will be used to store calculated distances
list = [0]

# Loop through each row in the data frame using pairwise
for (i1, row1), (i2, row2) in pairwise(df.iterrows()):
```

https://medium.com/how-to-use-google-distance-matrix-api-in-python/how-to-use-google-distance-matrix-api-in-python-ef9cd895303c

I looked up what non_type means so I tried printing out to see if anything would print out and it works fine. I mostly use R and don't use python much.

```
for (i,j) in pairwise(df2.iterrows()):
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from copy import deepcopy
from datetime import datetime
from IPython.display import HTML
import json
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import arcgis.network as network
import arcgis.geocoding as geocoding
from itertools import tee



user_name = 'username'
password = 'password'
my_gis = GIS('https://www.arcgis.com', user_name, password)

route_service_url = my_gis.properties.helperServices.route.url
route_service = network.RouteLayer(route_service_url, gis=my_gis)

for (i,j) in pairwise(df2.iterrows()):
    stop1_geocoded = geocoding.geocode(i)
    stop2_geocoded = geocoding.geocode(j)

    stops = '{0},{1}; {2},{3}'.format(stop1_geocoded[0]['attributes']['X'],
                                      stop1_geocoded[0]['attributes']['Y'],
                                      stop2_geocoded[0]['attributes']['X'],
                                      stop2_geocoded[0]['attributes']['Y'])
    route_layer = network.RouteLayer(route_service_url, gis=my_gis)
    result = route_layer.solve(stops=stops, return_directions=False, return_routes=True, 
                               output_lines='esriNAOutputLineNone', return_barriers=False, 
                               return_polygon_barriers=False, return_polyline_barriers=False)
    travel_time = result['routes']['features'][0]['attributes']['Total_TravelTime']

    print("Total travel time is {0:.2f} min".format(travel_time))
```

The expected output is a list of drive times as a list. I tried appended all to a dataframe, and that would be ideal. So the ideal output would be 3 columns - address 1, address 2, and drive time. The code does work with one address at a time (instead of i,j it's just two addresses as strings and no for statement).

example:

```
          Address_1                                        Address_2
0  1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500    2 15th St NW, Washington
1  400 Broad St, Seattle, WA 98109                   325 5th Ave N, Seattle

         drive_time
0  7 minutes
1  3 minutes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the pairwise function is unnecessary. Just wrap the arcGIS code in a function that will return the time to you, and this way you can map the values as a new column on your dataframe.

Also make sure that you import the time library, which is not noted on the arcGIS documentation but is needed to run this.

`

```
def getTime(row):    

    try:
        stop1_geocoded = geocoding.geocode(row.df_column_1)
        stop2_geocoded = geocoding.geocode(row.df_column_2)

        stops = '{0},{1}; {2},{3}'.format(stop1_geocoded[0]['attributes']['X'],
                                          stop1_geocoded[0]['attributes']['Y'],
                                          stop2_geocoded[0]['attributes']['X'],
                                          stop2_geocoded[0]['attributes']['Y'])

        route_layer = network.RouteLayer(route_service_url, gis=my_gis)
        result = route_layer.solve(stops=stops, return_directions=False, return_routes=True, 
                                   output_lines='esriNAOutputLineNone', return_barriers=False, 
                                   return_polygon_barriers=False, return_polyline_barriers=False)

        travel_time = result['routes']['features'][0]['attributes']['Total_TravelTime']
        time = "Total travel time is {0:.2f} min".format(travel_time)

        return time

    except RuntimeError:
        return 

streets['travel_time'] = streets.apply(getTime, axis=1)
```

`